# Cascade delete on many-to-many between same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce, cascade

I'm trying to create a many-to-many relation between the same table in SQL Server.

I have one table `Object` with columns `ObjectId` and `Name`.

The relation follows these rules:

- a child can have many parents
- a parent can have many children
- ObjectA can be a child of ObjectB and ObjectB can be a child of ObjectA
- but an object cannot be a direct child of itself

So I create a second table `ObjectRelation` with columns `ParentId` and `ChildId` and of course I want these relations to be deleted by cascade.

But when I try this in SQL Server I get the error

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ObjectRelation_Object1' on table 'tblADMembership' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

In SQL Server Compact I get

> *The referential relationship will result in a cyclical reference that is not allowed.*

I've done some research and I understand why I get these errors, but is there a way around this that will also work on SQL Server Compact (so no stored procedures)? Or is there a better way to model this relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across a similar problem myself....I ended up removing the foreign key. Cyclic deletion logic was pushed to Code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a treeview. This is a code to delete that was useful to me:
(I save the id into the value property and I'm using a entity model framwork to delete) 
Maybe can help someone

```
private void removeRecursive(TreeNode parentToDelete)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode tn in parentToDelete.ChildNodes)
            removeRecursive(tn);

        long id = long.Parse(parentToDelete.Value);
        Category deleteCat = context.Categories.Single(x => x.Id ==id);
        context.Categories.DeleteObject(deleteCat);
    }
```

PD sorry about my english it's awful...